# Symfony check whether jQuery already included

Tags: php, jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there any way to check in sfContext whether jQuery library is already added,
using:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->addJavascript('/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js');
```

or

```
addJavascript('jquery-1.4.2.min.js', sfView::getContext());
```

or

```
use_javascript('jquery-1.4.2.min.js');
```

in the templates?

Seems to me that adding more jQuery's stops their action.

Comment: really ? you must be mistaken ! **we need moar jquery !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your own check.

1. Use your own `sfWebResponse`
2. Override `addJavascript`
3. Add the check

So create a new `myWebResponse.class.php` file in `/lib/response/` folder (create it), with this code :

```
class myWebResponse extends sfWebResponse 
{
  public function addJavascript($file, $position = '', $options = array())
  {
    $this->validatePosition($position);

    // check if the file to add is jquery
    // nb: you might update the regex 
    if (preg_match('/jquery/i', $file))
    {
      // retrieve all loaded js
      $files = array_keys($this->getJavascripts());

      // check if one them containt jquery
      // nb: you might update the regex 
      $isJquery = preg_grep("/jquery/i", $files);

      // jquery found so do not add the file
      if ( ! empty($isJquery))
      {
        return;
      }
    }

    $this->javascripts[$position][$file] = $options;
  }
```

Then, use your new response by default. In your `apps/frontend/config/factories.yml`,  add:

```
all:
  response:
    class: myWebResponse
```

You're done.