# what happens if there are two canonical tags in a page?

Tags: symfony1, seo, duplicates, canonical-link

I am trying to add canonical structure for articles since Google is assuming that I am duplicating contents.

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and the success page is included in a layout and layout has its own canonical tag. I am adding another canonical tag dynamically in success page and it is resulting in multiple canonical tags.

I cannot remove canonical tag from layout since it will be used by many other templates..

I need to remove the canonical tag coming from layout and insert my own only for few templates ( dynamically) .

Is it possible to achieve it.

Comment: What is the canonical from the layout? I can't see why you put a canonical in the global layout o_O

Comment: Hi .. j0k.!! 
It is just continuation of my last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947313/how-to-add-canonical-tag-the-pages-that-are-derived-from-same-link 

In layout.php , previous developers had put a canonical link and I cannot remove it now. I just want to remove it for my news article pages and I want to add a new one.

Comment: I think you should do sth [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813920/symfony-check-whether-jquery-already-included) but for the link. Checked if a canonical is already here, if so, removed the older otherwise add the canonical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in such occasions you separate the markup of your link in a template which includes logic to modify the attributes of the link based on where they are being _included. Have a little look at [this article](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php) to see some more examples of templating engines.

Hope this helps